# React multiple criteria filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, stackblitz

I created like a shop, it's not for production, just for practice. I want to filter by criteria(size, model), it works when I add model, click filter, then add size, click filter to filter sizes..

Problem is, for example, when I remove all sizes and click filter on size filtering it returns all products, which would be okay if there are no filter criteria at all but there is still brand criteria..

Here is Stackblitz project: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jevhb9](http://Link)

Answer (score 0):

your issue can be found with

```
{filterArray.length > 0 ? (
      <ProductGrid products={filterArray} />
    ) : (
      <ProductGrid products={products} />
)}
```

when the app render's the content after clicking the size filter, your filterArray is empty and therefore returns the products array which contains all your data

Comment: Yes, I know that,  but I think the problem is that I create new set every time when I call the function..

Comment: why not store all your filters in a state, and have 1 button filter on the state?

Comment: It’s probably the best option, I’ll try it, thank you